# Creating a local package repository for offline installation of MikTex

Tags: packages, miktex, installing

I'm trying to create a local package repository to be used during installing miktex on a system not connected to the internet. I want to install miktex and load the packages I need in one command (or at least, do it completely unattended by user).

As a start I have a directory, C:\MyRepo\ containing these 3 files:

1. miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma
2. miktex-zzdbb-2.9.tar.lzma
3. floatrow.zip ( package file)

I go to run my installer as follows:

basic-miktex-2.9.6643-x64.exe --auto-install=yes --unattended --install-from-local-repository --local-package-repository=C:\MyRepo

When I run this, I get "The specified local repository does not exist".
However, if I fully install miktex, and then in the package manager specify my local repo, it seems to accept it as a local repository.

Is there something I'm doing wrong on the command line args to specify the package repo, or perhaps something not quite right with my local repo directory contents?

Comment: Why do you want to specifiy it during  installation of the basic installer? It doesn't look for an repository, it contains the packages.

Comment: I assumed I needed to a local repository during installation, considering it seems to provide that as a flag. Is there a post-installation command line option for adding packages offline? I don't understand "It doesn't look for an repository, it contains the packages. "

Comment: the basic installer is a self-contained installer. You can after the installation set the repository for following package installations.

Comment: Is there a way to set the local repository after installation, from command line?

Comment: Try mpm -help. I'm  not quite sure if it still works.

Comment: thanks, i found the necessary command switches and will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These steps outline installing miktex itself, and then installing packages from a local repo. The local repo contains .tar.lzma files, as well as `miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma`, `miktex-zzdb2-2.9.tar.lzma` and `miktex-zzdb3-2.9.tar.lzma`. Packages to install are described as a comma separated list.

$appInstaller points to the basic-miktex-2.9.6643-x64.exe.
$miktexPackageInstaller points to mpm.exe, which is located in hte miktex program file directory after install.

```
# install miktex unattended, for all users (requires admin). uses cmd args shown from -h option
Start-Process -Wait "$appInstaller" -ArgumentList "--auto-install=yes --unattended --shared"

Start-Process -Wait "$miktexPackageInstaller" -argumentList "--admin --repository=$localPackageRepo --install=package1,package2,package3"
```