# Local Package MikTeX

Tags: miktex

I had to uninstall my Laptops Windows, then re-installed the MikTex 2.9 and editors: TexStudio and TexMaker. However, in the first run, a notification window is popping my asking me to choose the local repository, since I could not find any such repository, in the MikTeX console, I chose http://ctan.mirror.solo-server.net, and int the window popping up in the TexTudio, I selected remote package repository. and this time, running the codes, each and every package was being installed which made me think what if I do not have access to Internet. But, I am 100% sure that before reinstalling the new windows, I was not downloading the packages, maybe I was using packages fro so-called "local" repository. I wonder if I can set up that local repository again so that I do not need to install each and every package? Or, maybe it would be better to ask how to access the local package repository since I could not find this in appData.

Comment: A local package repository is a directory on you machine which contains a copy of  an internet repository. You can download its content using some ftp manager such as FileZilla  using this address: [ftp.dante.de](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/)

Comment: My issue is to find the directory of the local repository

Comment: It's up to you to define one and validate it via `MiKTeX Settings` (preferably as Administrator), `General` tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bernard has pointed out (but since relocated) the MiKTeX repository of approx 3620 package files is
ftp://tug.org/tex-archive/systems/windows/miktex/tm/packages/  where the readme says

> This directory contains the "Total MiKTeX" package set. To install
> MiKTeX, download and run the MiKTeX Net Installer. For more
> information, visit the MiKTeX Project Page at [www.miktex.org](http://www.miktex.org).

One point of the package manager is to avoid downloading ALL those files, thus to that end during install it can be pre-loaded with an older local (or LAN) set which can then be updated ad hoc.

If you have a folder with a set of files such as miktex-bibtex-bin-**2.9.tar.lzma** or similar you can point to that location.

The quantity of .tar.lzma files you find may be few in which case its best to get a part working **basic** set of upacked .exe and .sty etc. files first (I use a recent portable install).

see also related why [NOT to look for .zip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214108/installing-zip-packages-with-the-miktex-package-manager-from-a-local-repository) and [creating a repository](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424050/creating-a-local-package-repository-for-offline-installation-of-miktex)

If you cant find a large group of similar files, then it is unlikely you had a repository (just a very full install) If you wish to build one from scratch for multiple users / locations / offline see the [How to guide](https://miktex.org/howto/deploy-miktex) beware the full download is 2.9 GB equivalent to a full TeX Live installation.

Comment: I have already installed the MikTeX, however, I searched all folders, I do not have any files with .tar.lzma extention. 
If I have to build up such "Local Repository", could you list the steps since I am confused because I do not remember if I had done this before on my old windows.

Comment: @B.Bornay answer updated see last para